# Android - how can i know when gridview has reached the bottom?

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

I'm building an app that loads images from JSON and displays them as grid view.
the problem is that there are hundreds of images and i want to load 20 each time, 
I want to download more pictures from the server when the scroll reaches the bottom.
so, how can i tell when the grid [image]view reaches the bottom?
I've searched the web and couldn't figure this one...

anyone have ideas?

I'm adding a photo of an app that does something very similar to what i want.
thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [setOnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOnScrollListener%28android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener%29) to your GridView.

Here is the code example:

```
gridView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
       {
        if(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount){
            // End has been reached
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState){

    }
});
```

Comment: what if there are less items then a pages length?? it would be fired as soon it starts

Comment: It was calling twice.

Comment: @dangalg is right. It will always fired as soon as it starts and continously

Comment: There is some good examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095857/onscrolllistener-updating-gridview

Answer (score 1):

And here is my solution, You may want to simply override the `onOverScrolled` method :

```
@Override
protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
    super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);

    View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()));

    if(diff==0) {
           //overscroll on bottom
       } else {
           //overscroll on top
       }    
}
```