# Android Swipe Refresh Layout scroll up to refresh

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I've implemented a swipe refresh layout for my grid view and it works perfectly if I pull (scroll) downwards for the refresh to be called.

However, I'm trying to figure out how to refresh when the user scrolls up.  So when the user reaches the last of the items in the grid (my limit is 10) so when the user sees all ten and then pulls upwards or tries to continue to scroll how can I then refresh?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so people either a: don't know the answer to this question or b: they're not willing to share the knowledge.

Anyway after a long time I came up with my own solution.  I added a scroll listener to my grid, and calculated when I scrolled to the bottom of the screen, at this point I recall the onRefresh() method from the swipe to refresh...

***EDIT*** 
***to add further info***

So, after I did some research to calculate when the user reached the bottom of a grid view I followed questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276396/android-how-can-i-know-when-gridview-has-reached-the-bottom) and others to get that.  Below is my code that I had to alter in order have it work with the native refreshing functionality.  My alterations were to prevent constant refreshing.  So included in my if statement is a check that it's not currently refreshing, so when I reached the bottom it refreshed, but I didn't have that check so it constantly refreshed.  I then had to do a check against the total amount of items in my grid, as when the user reached the last item (very last item) the app also kept refreshing and there was nothing to break the cycle.  Hopefully this is of some help...

```
        worldBeersGrid.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            int position = firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount;
            int limit = totalItemCount;
            int totalItems = sharedpreferences.getInt("WORLD ITEM COUNT", 0);

            Log.i("TOTAL WORLD ITEMS", String.valueOf(totalItems));
            Log.i("LIMIT :::::::::::: ", String.valueOf(limit));
            Log.i("POSITION ::::::::::::", String.valueOf(position));
            Log.i("REFRESHING :::::::::::::::", String.valueOf(swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()));

            if(position>=limit && totalItemCount>0 && !swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing() && position <totalItems){
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                //In the below method I made my call to my ws...
                onRefresh();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey @DJ-DOO, I just tried replicating this behavior and am having trouble. I used http://nlopez.io/swiperefreshlayout-with-listview-done-right/ to fix the early refreshing on my gridview, but I'm having trouble calculating where the bottom of my list is. Could you edit your answer with how you calculated the bottom? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

See my answer in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867204/swiperefreshlayout-pull-from-bottom)

SwipeRefreshLayout from Android Support Library version 21  does not support pull from bottom.
I have made modification SwipeRefreshLayoutBottom with is based on original SwipeRefreshLayout code.
It is  fully based on original Google code with just inversion of coordinates and newly writed canChildScrollDown method. All modification are marked as TODO.

[Bitbucker repository](https://bitbucket.org/andreyice/swiperefreshlayoutbottom)

Answer (score 3):

You try this way

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    boolean enable = false;
    if(listView != null && listView.getChildCount() > 0){
        // check if the first item of the list is visible
        boolean firstItemVisible = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0;
        // check if the top of the first item is visible
        boolean topOfFirstItemVisible = listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
        // enabling or disabling the refresh layout
        enable = firstItemVisible && topOfFirstItemVisible;
    }
    swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(enable);
}});
```

Answer (score 3):

Another answer if anybody is still interested. In order to refresh when scrolling down, I've implemented the onRefreshListerner() on the swipeRefreshLayout.

```
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.swipe_messages);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

            ( new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    refresh();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

But in order to refresh when scrolling up and only when I've got to the end of the list, I've implemented OnTouchListener() on the list which includes the swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true) to start the effect:

```
    listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == listView.getAdapter().getCount() -1 &&
                        listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= listView.getHeight())
                {

                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                    ( new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            refresh();
                        }
                    }, 1000);

                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Of course you have to disable the swipeRefreshLayout after updating your list:

```
public void refresh (){
    //Do something neat here to refresh your list
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

I've used this answer to know when I've got to the end of the list:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10235887/6144027

Answer (score 1):

I have another way:

```
binding.contentListScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (!binding.contentListScroll.canScrollVertically(1))
                {
                    binding.swiperefresh.setRefreshing(true);
                    YourRefreshMethod();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Good solution. It is also suitable without `SwipeRefreshLayout` at all.