# SwipeRefreshLayout - Pull From Bottom

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

Is there a way to use `SwipeRefreshLayout` to refresh `ListView` when it's pulled from bottom?

I created pull from top, but I would also need pull from bottom. There are many tutorials on how to create pull from top, but I couldn't find any tutorials for pull from bottom?

Comment: Maybe because you were searching for the wrong thing? What you are describing is an [**endless ListView**](https://www.google.at/?q=endless%20listview#q=endless+listview)

Answer (score 19):

SwipeRefreshLayout from Android Support Library version 21  does not support pull from bottom.
I have made modification SwipeRefreshLayoutBottom with is based on original SwipeRefreshLayout code.
It is  fully based on original Google code with just inversion of coordinates and overridden implementation of canChildScrollDown method. All modification are marked as TODO.

[Bitbucker repository](https://bitbucket.org/andreyice/swiperefreshlayoutbottom)

Comment: Thanks AndreyICE. I ported your code to an Android Studio 1.2 project and created an aar library. The project also includes the gradle build. It's available at https://github.com/JohannBlake/SwipeRefreshLayoutBottom

Comment: This answer should be accepted! Thank you AndreyICE

Comment: It should not. The asker is looking for both top and bottom.

Comment: also if you place SwipeRefreshLayoutBottom.java file inside android.support.v4.widget package in your project, the original package-private classes CircleImageView and MaterialProgressDrawable from support library will be available. So you won't have to keep a copy of these classes.

Answer (score 17):

Use this great library:
[OrangeGangsters SwipyRefreshLayout](https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/SwipyRefreshLayout)

So you can swipe both from top and bottom and supports API 9+.

Comment: Great component. Just one issue though, the rotating arrow animation sometimes do not properly render and the arrow is not displayed.

Comment: You can create an issue in the repo, if you are sure about that problem

Comment: This is cool layout but it's some bugs. Eg: pull up-to-bottom then pull bottom-to-up without lifting my finger, or sometimes refresh icon appears strange.

Answer (score 3):

Library [omadahealth/SwipyRefreshLayout](https://github.com/omadahealth/SwipyRefreshLayout) must be the answer for your case.

Below Codes make your `Recycler view pull up from bottom to refresh` :

```
<com.omadahealth.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
    style="@style/View_MatchParent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:srl_direction="bottom"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        style="@style/View_MatchParent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</com.omadahealth.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem and I have solved it with a combination of swipeRefreshLayout and a touch event in my list. Here is the link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41701320/6144027

Answer (score -6):

No, you can't do that with SwipeRefreshLayout. You need to implement your own layout, which is not that hard.

Check this
http://erikw.eu/open-source-android-pull-to-refresh-library/
and this
http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Implementing-Pull-to-refresh-(like-in-Facebook-mobile-app)-for-ANDROID-using-Titanium