# Android Swipe Up to Refresh ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, swiperefreshlayout

I have to implement android swipe up to refresh listview. I got sample code from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/05/android-swipe-down-to-refresh-listview-tutorial/). But in this code it is swipe down to refresh listview. And I want it in swipe up to refresh listview. If anyone know answer then please explain or suggest me link from where I can understand from beginning. Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please Use

[Link](https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/SwipyRefreshLayout) Library for scrolling bottom/Up by setting direction.

You can use other SO links too

[SwipeRefreshLayout - Pull From Bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867204/swiperefreshlayout-pull-from-bottom)

Comment: [Please avoid link-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)

Comment: sure'll take care next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SwipeRefreshLayout,The layout you need to refresh should give inside this layout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
  android:id="@+id/sw_refresh"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <!--layout which should be refreshed should come here-->

      <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

       </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

You can see the complete implementation at [Android swipe to refresh listview layout](http://codesfor.in/android-swipe-to-refresh-listview-example/)

Answer (score -2):

Previously we used to implement a custom swipe view to detect the swipe down. But android made our day easier by introducing SwipeRefreshLayout in android.support.v4 to detect the vertical swipe on any view.

Below link shows show step by step procedure

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/05/android-swipe-down-to-refresh-listview-tutorial/

Comment: You obviously didn't read the question, which asked for swipe UP not DOWN.