# SwipeRefreshLayout that can be swiped from bottom

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I want to use a SwipeRefreshLayout but make it swipeable from the bottom instead of from the top.

I tried rotating both the Layout and the RecyclerView, but that only changed where the indicator is, not the behavior.

I also looked at this [implementation](https://bitbucket.org/andreyice/swiperefreshlayoutbottom/src/master/), but this overrides a very old version of the library.

I don't wanna use a 3rd party library, I'm sure the original SwipeRefreshLayout can be modified to make it work from the bottom. But how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwipeRefreshLayout - Pull From Bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867204/swiperefreshlayout-pull-from-bottom)

Comment: I already mentioned the answer in my question. It's a very old answer and doesn't work anymore

Comment: I'm on the same quest right now - and yes, everything I've seen so far is the really old stuff. And so far, I've got the impression that a proper solution right now would still be to copy-paste and adapt the current incarnation of the jetpack SwipeRefreshLayout.